# Select all Elements on a page

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a function in javascript which clicks on every element (links, buttons,...) on my page. All elements should be disabled by default. I am using this for my testing environment in Selenium to check whether all elements on my page are deactivated.

Comment: I was trying to get all Links with a function provided from selenium: selenium.getAllLinks() and I tried with click(). Also with getAllLinks() I am not able to get any link...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At first, get all elements on your page:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

Now that you get them, make a mouse-event, make a loop and apply the event on every element:

```
var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) 
{    
    elements[i].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your quick reply! I can follow your code and it makes sence to me. Unfortunatly I am not able to get any element out of document.getElementsByTagName("*");

Comment: I've changed some typo's in the code, maybe it works better now?
Also make sure you call the function that will test the clicks AFTER the document is loaded. If I put it in the onLoad statement of the body, my code works fine!

Comment: So if you are executing the code your browser clicks on every link? Well actually, if the links are active, the first link which has been clicked should redirect you to the next page. If the links are disabled, nothing should happen. That is how I expect it should work. However, now I am able to get alle the links of the page with my selenium.getAllLinks. Although, the clickEvent doesnt seem to do anything.