# * { font-family: 'Lato' } with js

Tags: javascript, css

I want to set the global font with JS.

currently css:

```
* {
    font-family: 'Lato'
}
```

It only works when I use *. using body instead does not work

I could change if for body like this:

```
document.body.style.fontFamily = "Lato"
```

But I want a js version for the * selector.

Comment: Why isn't `body` work in your css?

Comment: they vote me down for the answer you are searching for...`var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518015/select-all-elements-on-a-page

Comment: Yep, same for me messerbill. I answered that too. Clearly people think that that's the wrong approach, even though it's what the OP asked literally considering the last sentence of his question. I can agree on that though. You don't want to use JS to set the font of all your elements.

Comment: @messerbill @Jon - Its probably because you have answered `document.getElementsByTagName("*").style.fontFamily = "Lato";` whereas the correct answer is `document.getElementsByTagName("*")[0].style.fontFamily = "Lato";`. Please do recheck before you post an answer.

Comment: @Gibin Ealias I corrected it. The downvoters could've done that too.

Comment: @GibinEalias: That would only change the *first* of them.

Comment: @jon koeter - Done :)

Comment: @GibinEalias no. I iterated over the Collection `var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].style.fontFamily = "Lato"
}` ..... rediclious

Comment: `Please do recheck before you post an answer` Please read the answers before downvoting them

Comment: @messerbill: Indeed, yours (I can see deleted answers thanks to >10k rep) was the only answer that *correctly* showed applying it to all elements directly. I don't think that's a good idea, but it did correctly do what you wanted it to do (and would work provided nothing on the page ever changed afterward), unlike the others posted in a similar vein...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to append a `style` element to do this reasonably. (To do it **un**reasonably, spin through every element on the page and set it via `.style`. See below.)

It's easy enough to do:

```
var style = document.createElement("style");
style.type = "text/css";
style.appendChild(
    document.createTextNode("* { font-family: 'Lato' }")
);
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

Of course, all the normal CSS rules apply. An element with a more-specific rule setting `font-family`, or a `.style` property setting it, will still use that more-specific setting.

This has the advantage that it applies to new elements added after you've done it as well as existing elements.

---

***If*** you wanted to visit every element on the page to set `.style.fontFamily` explicitly on each, the quick-and-dirty version on modern browsers is:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("*"), function(el) {
    el.style.fontFamily = "Lato";
});
```

`getElementsByTagName("*")` will access the browser's list of all elements in the document, if it already has one; and build it if not. (This is in contrast to `querySelectorAll`, which is required to always build a new one.) Then we loop over it by borrowing `forEach` from `Array.prototype`. (See the "array-like objects" part of [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) for details.)